# Unserialize through query at database level itself

Tags: mysql

I have a column value stored in the database as:

> a:2:{i:0;s:2:"US";i:1;s:2:"19";}

I want to unserialize it during the mysql query rather than using the php  `unserialize` function after fetching the data.
I want to do it this way so I can join another table with the serialized value. This would avoid executing a separate query after unserializing it with php, just for the joined data.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is. You can't do it.

Comment: Also, if you need to unserialize it in order to perform a `JOIN` operation, you should *really* reconsider your database design. This begs for further [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Yeah the solution is for normalization but this is a foreign DB. I dont have any  right to modify it. Iam utilizing the data

Comment: I think `You can't do it` part would be better changed by `It's very hard to achieve and probably not the best way to do it`. Even better if you can think of alternatives to solving the problem.

Comment: This is the only correct answer for this question. If the value is serialized using a php function, it should be deserialized using the corresponding [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function. There's no other reliable or deterministic way.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

For example, if you have a record like this:

```
a:5:{s:9:"invoiceid";s:1:"8";s:8:"balance";i:5;s:14:"broughtforward";i:3;s:6:"userid";s:5:"13908";s:10:"customerid";s:1:"3";}
```

You can use the below SELECT statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',1),':',-1) AS fieldname1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',2),':',-1) AS fieldvalue1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',3),':',-1) AS fieldname2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',4),':',-1) AS fieldvalue2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',5),':',-1) AS fieldname3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',6),':',-1) AS fieldvalue3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',7),':',-1) AS fieldname4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',8),':',-1) AS fieldvalue4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',9),':',-1) AS fieldname5,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data,';',10),':',-1) AS fieldvalue5
FROM table;
```

Check this for reference: [How to unserialize data using mysql without using php](http://www.russellengland.com/2012/07/how-to-unserialize-data-using-mysql.html)

Comment: This solution could prove problematic if some of your serialized data contains colons or semicolons.

Comment: Works fine for me -- +1    Kyle does have a point about semicolons though -- but doesn't mean your post wasn't helpful.

Comment: Agreed with @espradley! Thanks Remi, this saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: @KyleRidolfo easy way to solve that is to include the quote marks in the substrings, e.g. `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_data, '";', 2), ':"', -1) fieldvalue1`, although that does mean that if you are unlucky enough to have that combo in your data, then you may be out of luck entirely as you have nothing else to piggy back off the spec to search really, unless you had some sort of regex or fuzz on the length number before the value.

Answer (score 19):

How about this? This is a MySQL user-defined function with embedded php:

```
CREATE FUNCTION unserialize_php RETURNS STRING SONAME 'unserialize_php.so';
```

Usage example:

```
SELECT unserialize_php('O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:1:"a";s:4:"aaaa";s:1:"b";s:4:"bbbb";}', "$obj->a") 
AS 'unserialized';
```

```
+--------------+
| unserialized |
+--------------+
| aaaa         |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
drop function unserialize_php;
```

Source: https://github.com/junamai2000/mysql_unserialize_php

You can create a MySQL user-defined function and call `zend_eval_string` inside of the function so that you can bring back PHP variables to a MySQL result. I implemented a sample program. You can try it.

Comment: This is very cool. Does not appear to work with php7 though, since zend seems to have changed a lot of the API

Answer (score 12):

From http://www.blastar.biz/2013/11/28/how-to-use-mysql-to-search-in-php-serialized-fields/

Standard array

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_field_here REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"your_value_here".*'
```

Associative array

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_field_here REGEXP '.*"array_key_here";s [0-9]+:"your_value_here".*'
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a very bad practice to add programming language dependent structures to database. If you do so, you always have to rely on that language.

The best approach is to have normalized table structure (different fields or tables).

The next approach is to save data as a delimited string (e.g.: `0,US,1,19`). Then you can use MySQL's `SUBSTRING()` or to use standard serialization mechanisms like JSON encode.

Comment: thats right but the value is not inserted by external app. So, I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by [kchteam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270065/kchteam), MySQLToolBox library comes handy for this purpose using a custom defined MySQL function `getPhpSerializedArrayValueByKey` available here https://github.com/KredytyChwilowki/MySQLToolBox/blob/master/getPhpSerializedArrayValueByKey.sql.

After adding this function, you can retrieve any value in the serialized array by using the following syntax,

```
SELECT getPhpSerializedArrayValueByKey(column_name, 'array_key') AS deseializedArrayValue FROM table_name
```

The given array can be unserialized like,

```
SELECT getPhpSerializedArrayValueByKey('a:2:{i:0;s:2:"US";i:1;s:2:"19";}
', 'key_to_retrieve') AS key_to_retrieve
```

Answer (score 0):

For serialized arrays You can use function getPhpSerializedArrayValueByKey from [here](https://github.com/KredytyChwilowki/MySQLToolBox)

Comment: You can get value of serialized (using php) associative array by string key. When value of array is another array or object you get it as it is (serialized).
For Simple types like int, strings etc. you get them directly.
At https://github.com/KredytyChwilowki/MySQLToolBox you can get examples of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table simply in this way

```
    SELECT 
    table_to_join.ID as table_to_join_ID ,
    serialized_table.ID AS   serialized_table_ID,
FROM
    table_to_join
        LEFT JOIN
    serialized_table  ON  serialized_table.array_field  REGEXP CONCAT_WS('','.s:[0-9];s:', table_to_join.ID ,';.') ;
```

Take mention. I use index from 0 to 9 in table. If you have other indexes you must correct regexp