# MySQL: Getting a value from a string using a regex?

Tags: mysql, regex

One column returns such values:

```
Something";s:5:"value";s:3:"900";s:11:"print_
```

I want to extract all numbers that are at least 3 digits long, in the above case thats 900. How can I do that in MySQL? Maybe using a regex? I cant use any index, the length of the string and the number in the string can be different.

Thanks!

Comment: if mysql doesn't support regex. Then I think you should get this value from mysql to your variable then use the regex functionality of whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try unserialize() it if you are using PHP! And then var_dump it to see the strings and arrays

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335970/unserialize-through-query-at-database-level-itself

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract them using MySQL, use any other language for that.
What you can do is include a Where Clause, that will make the work easier for your script.

Assuming your column is called "serialized" in the table "example"

```
SELECT serialized FROM example WHERE serialized REGEXP '[0-9]{3,}'
```

Please note that REGEXP is just outputting 1 or 0

After you did the query, use the regex functions of your language do extract the numbers like so:

([0-9]{3,})*