# Find a particular value in serialize array yii 2.0

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I am working with Yii 2.0. Here is my field which has serialize value now i want to find that if 94 exist in this field than i need all values from this row.
post_parents: a:2:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:2:"94";}

All efforts will be appriciated & thanks in advance

Comment: Does tag `sql` have any important to this question? If not please remove tag `sql`.

Comment: thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

This is a sql problem rather than Yii. Here is sam problem: [Unserialize through query at database level itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335970/unserialize-through-query-at-database-level-itself)

Build query like that:

```
$query->andWhere('your_field_here REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"your_value_here".*');
```

Comment: `public function actionTest(){
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select('*')
            ->from('posts')
            ->where('post_parent REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"8".*');
        $rows = $query->all();
        print_r($rows);
    }`

Comment: is there any change required

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE post_parent REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"93".*'
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1139
    [2] => Got error 'this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from regexp
)`

Comment: it's db problem not yii. Use another db engine or enable utf support.

Comment: yeah i have enable