# Serialize data in mysql column from another table data

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, deserialization

I have deserialized data in one table where columns are like below

```
Col1  *  Col2  *  Col3  * Col4  *  Col5  * Col6  *....Col60+/-
------------------------------------------------------
  6     "type"  "radio" "title"  "Which..."
```

This data is to be serialized and inserted in another table's columns as below

```
a:1:{i:6;a:9:{s:4:"type";s:5:"radio";s:5:"title";s:24:"Which option is correct?";s:10:"validation";a:1:{s:8:"required";b:1;}s:8:"subtitle";s:26:"Select the correct option*";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:11:"conditional";a:4:{s:6:"active";b:0;s:6:"status";b:0;s:6:"change";b:1;s:5:"logic";a:0:{}}s:6:"m_type";s:3:"mcq";s:7:"tooltip";s:0:"";s:8:"settings";a:11:{s:12:"hidden_label";b:0;s:7:"options";a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Option 1";s:5:"score";s:1:"1";s:3:"num";s:0:"";}i:1;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Option 2";s:5:"score";s:1:"0";s:3:"num";s:0:"";}i:2;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Option 3";s:5:"score";s:1:"0";s:3:"num";s:0:"";}}s:7:"columns";s:1:"1";s:8:"vertical";b:1;s:8:"centered";b:0;s:6:"others";b:0;s:7:"o_label";s:6:"Others";s:4:"icon";s:5:"57742";s:7:"shuffle";b:0;s:4:"type";s:4:"none";s:9:"parameter";s:0:"";}}}
```

Can this be done on mysql alone or do I need to use php functions along with mysql to serialize the data?

Comment: is this a valid json format ?  i don't know want you want but you can use Json_object('a',table.col1, 'i',table.col2) in select statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unserialize through query at database level itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335970/unserialize-through-query-at-database-level-itself)

Comment: @Sean The link you shared creates substring from the serialized column. I want the other way round.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy it was primarily to show that MySQL does not have a function similar to php's `serialize()`. You will need to retrieve the table data, serialize in php, and then insert into your table. You can not do it in MySQL only.

Comment: @shivamdhankani - That's not json, it's a PHP array that have been serialized using PHP's `serialize()`-function. And since it's a PHP-specific function, there's no MySQL function that gives you the same result.

Comment: The biggest question would probably be _why_ you need to do this? If you already have the data in a more normalized form, why store it serialized in a column as well/instead?