# How can I parse multiple values in a single field of a mySql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I am working with a real-estate database in mySql. This is used with a wordpress site.
Each property that is listed has related agents in a joined table. There may be more than 1 agent to a property.
However, multiple agents are listed in a single field. (So, join is 1-1).
Here is an example

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"1995";i:1;s:3:"260";}
```

So it appears that this is some sort of array implementation. I don't have much experience with this, as it is a bad way of storing data in a relational DB anyway.
In this example, there are 2 agents. 
I know that:
 - the first "2" probably refers to the number of agents.
 - "1995" and "260" are the record-ids of the agent's record.
How would I craft a SQL statement to extract these two record ids (and find related data in the main record) from php?
If this is a cumbersome solution, I'd want to create a new SQL view to make access easier. Is this possible?
If there are any, I can't find any php functions that interprets this field.
Table redesign is not an option.

Edit:
As I was reading through the answers to a similar question as pointed out, I came to the conclusion that this is most probably impossible to do. And frankly ridiculous.
The solution entailed using the SUBSTRING_INDEX repeatedly. How many times, could vary every time. Even if the number of values is specified, it may not be possible to accomplish in MySQL. I will have to work with the limitations that this creates.

Comment: That is serialized PHP data. You can't unserialize it with MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unserialize through query at database level itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335970/unserialize-through-query-at-database-level-itself)

Comment: Do you own/admin the Wordpress? If so you could easily create a custom Query in a custom template of your child-theme in order to display those informations

Comment: @gael, yes, that was precisely what I intended to do. The problem is formatting the custom query in the first place. According to the similar question, mentioned above, it requires the use of SUBSTRING_INDEX a variable number of times. This is unfortunately "above my pay-grade".
Unless I can come up with some genius solution, I may have to admit defeat.

Answer (score 0):

The data format you mention is [php's serialization format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php). Before JSON took over the world, Rasmus Lerdorf and the php creators came up with their own way of doing it.

WordPress uses lots of this stuff.

[php's `unserialize()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) converts it from that string representation into an appropriate php object.

If you must, you can probably use [MySQL string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) like [LOCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to extract certain values from those serialized strings. But that will be a huge pain in the neck, and very specific to the kind of object that's serialized.