# How to get a specific value of an array stored in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In a Mysql Database the value of a field is like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"3";}
```

The value i need here is the 3.

If it is a normal number i could sum up selected field with the query but like this i fail

Is it possible to make the math within the query or do i have to process the result of the query (how?) ?

**Update due to Answer of @kabirbaidhya**
Making the unserialize [here Online](https://de.functions-online.com/unserialize.html) gives the right result.

Processing the Query gives not the expected

```
function summe_bilden() 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $value = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT VALUE FROM wp_vxcf_leads JOIN wp_vxcf_leads_detail ON wp_vxcf_leads.id = wp_vxcf_leads_detail.lead_id WHERE name = 'stunden'");  
    foreach($value as $a)
        { 
         $arr = unserialize($a);
         var_dump($a);
         echo $arr[0];
        } 
          
}
```

> object(stdClass)#9463 (1) { ["VALUE"]=> string(18) "a:1:{i:0;s:1:"3";}" } object(stdClass)#9464 (1) { ["VALUE"]=> string(20) "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"9,5";}" } object(stdClass)#9465 (1) { ["VALUE"]=> string(20) "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"7,5";}" }

Update 2:
Final working code for me:

```
    foreach($value as $a)
    { 
     $array = $a->VALUE;
     $ar = unserialize($array);
     echo $ar[0];
     echo '</br>';
    }
```

Comment: Every number is normal , besides that extract the JSON content and calculate

Comment: this is json notation - are you storing json as entity? than calculation outside, after converting and extraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a value persisted in the database by serializing an array using PHP function [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

That means, the **only correct way** is the deserialize it back using PHP with its corresponding function [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

**Steps:**

1. Get the value from the the db with a query like `SELECT VALUE from your_table`.
2. Unserialize the value to get an PHP array which gives you the data you're looking for.

```
foreach($value as $a) { 
    $arr = unserialize($a->VALUE);
    var_dump($a);
    echo $arr[0];
}
```

**Note:** You shouldn't process it with mysql query alone - it's not reliable and is not deterministic for this use case.

Comment: i don´t get further with that....   just using your lines for testing  returns bool(false)

Comment: What did you do? Check your database query you used to extract the string. Did you check if it was correct? The unserialize function returns false if the input was invalid, read more - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: the query is ok - i checked it directly at phpmyadmin did you see my update on my original question?

Comment: @Arwed Just saw your updated query, and found the issue. Check my updated code. Your column name was `VALUE` so you should unserialize it's value instead of the whole object.

Comment: unserialize($a["VALUE"]);   doesn´t work, i got it working with the code above Update2   Anyway  thx for help

Comment: Oh, gotcha. It's an `stdClass` object so you need to use `->` operator. Corrected my code too.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: *****NO*****

---

there is not any serialize or unserialize function in sql

so you need to get all data from your sql and unserialize they, and finally get sum of your selected value. but pay attention my entered sample maybe have problem in big datas

example:

```
<?php

$query = {your query}

$sum = 0;

while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $column = $row['column'];
    $column = unserialize($column);
    
    $column = (int)$column;

    $sum = $sum + $column
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching for the term "unserialize($column)"   i found another post related to my question
[Unserialize through query at database level itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335970/unserialize-through-query-at-database-level-itself)

After some try and error for the right position i found this query working

```
SELECT VALUE, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VALUE,'"',2),'"',-1) AS stunden FROM wp_vxcf_leads JOIN wp_vxcf_leads_detail ON wp_vxcf_leads.id = wp_vxcf_leads_detail.lead_id WHERE name = 'stunden'
```

Comment: this query is not the correct way for your needs and only solve your problem. becuase your data is not a simple string that you wanna use substring. substringing is for spliting spe specific range of a string. not for getting X position of an serialized data. anyway. be care this query don't make another problems for you. good luck

Comment: think i already found the problems you mentioned :)    going this way and using sum() it gives the incorrect number  --->  7,5 + 9,5 + 3  gives me 19 instead of 20

Comment: This might work for one or two specific arrays with your use case. But it's not correct, since the serialized string could be far more complex depending on the length and type of elements it holds, not to mention they could be nested.